# Titanium XHR - Error parsing XML during XHR.SEND meanwhile not using XML parser knowingly

Tags: android, xml, xmlhttprequest, titanium, saxparseexception

i am trying to send a photo from Titanium Appcelerator mobile application to a webserver.

I am using the following example:

```
var upload_token = "hi! I am a token!";

var content = '';
var boundary = '---------------------------170062046428149';

content += '--'+ boundary + '\r\n';
content += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadToken"\r\n';
content += '\r\n';
content += upload_token + '\r\n';
content += '--'+ boundary + '\r\n';
content += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myNickname"\r\n';
content += '\r\n';
content += myNickname+'\r\n';
content += '--'+ boundary + '\r\n';

content += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nativePath"\r\n';
content += '\r\n';
content += 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app-name/tia-217296905.jpg\r\n';
content += '--'+ boundary + '\r\n';

content += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileContent"; filename="/appicon.png"\r\n';
content += 'Content-Type: binary/octet-stream\r\n';
content += '\r\n';

var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, '/appicon.png');
var full_content = Ti.createBuffer({value: content});
var fileStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source : file.read(), mode : Titanium.Stream.MODE_READ});
var content_size = full_content.append(Ti.Stream.readAll(fileStream));
Ti.API.debug('Appended File Size : ' + content_size ); // ==> same as file.size

content = '\r\n';
content += '--'+ boundary + '--\r\n';
full_content.append(Ti.createBuffer({value : content}));

xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
var send_data = full_content.toBlob();

var url = 'http://website.address/api/push_photo.php';
xhr.onload = function(e){
    console.log(e);
    alert("DONE!");
};
xhr.onerror = function(e){
    console.log(e);
};
xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
xhr.send({image:send_data});
```

Everything works as expected, file is transmitted to the server, and Titanium application in my mobile phone say "DONE!". Which means that xhr.onload has been triggered...

My question is regarding the error i am able to see in the developer console:

> [ERROR] :  XMLModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [13440,13649] Error parsing
>   XML [ERROR] :  XMLModule: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected
>   token (position:TEXT Array [ERROR] :  XMLModule: ( [ERROR] : 
>   XMLModule:     [upl...@7:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@42917730)
>   [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
>   [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
>   [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:82) [ERROR] : 
>   XMLModule:    at
>   ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:68) [ERROR] : 
>   XMLModule:    at
>   ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.getResponseXML(TiHTTPClient.java:562)
>   [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.network.HTTPClientProxy.getResponseXML(HTTPClientProxy.java:129)
>   [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeCallProperty(Native
>   Method) [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.callProperty(V8Object.java:73)
>   [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1155)
>   [ERROR] :  XMLModule:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) [ERROR] : 
>   XMLModule:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) [ERROR] : 
>   XMLModule:    at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:118)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: (KrollRuntimeThread) [7,13656] Error parsing
>   XML [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected
>   token (position:TEXT Array [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: ( [ERROR] : 
>   TiHTTPClient:     [upl...@7:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@42917730)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:82) [ERROR] : 
>   TiHTTPClient:     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:68) [ERROR] : 
>   TiHTTPClient:     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.getResponseXML(TiHTTPClient.java:562)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   ti.modules.titanium.network.HTTPClientProxy.getResponseXML(HTTPClientProxy.java:129)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeCallProperty(Native
>   Method) [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.callProperty(V8Object.java:73)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1155)
>   [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) [ERROR] : 
>   TiHTTPClient:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) [ERROR] : 
>   TiHTTPClient:     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:118)
>   [WARN] :   TiBlob: (KrollRuntimeThread) [24,13680] getFile not
>   supported for non-file blob types. [WARN] :   TiBlob:
>   (KrollRuntimeThread) [8,13688] getNativePath not supported for
>   non-file blob types. [INFO] :
>   {"code":0,"source":{"responseText":"Array\n(\n    [uploadToken] => hi!
>   I am a token!\n    [myNickname] => raholl\n    [nativePath] =>
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app-name/tia-217296905.jpg\n)\n","location":"http://********/api/push_photo.php","status":200,"domain":null,"readyState":4,"tlsVersion":0,"connectionType":"POST","validatesSecureCertificate":false,"statusText":"OK","username":null,"password":null,"allResponseHeaders":"null:HTTP/1.1
>   200
>   OK\nConnection:Keep-Alive\nContent-Length:166\nContent-Type:text/html\nDate:Wed,
>   18 May 2016 02:10:12 GMT\nKeep-Alive:timeout=5,
>   max=100\nServer:Apache/2.2.22
>   (Debian)\nVary:Accept-Encoding\nX-Android-Received-Millis:1463537845271\nX-Android-Sent-Millis:1463537844807\nX-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.33-1~dotdeb+7.1\n","responseXML":null,"responseData":{"file":null,"nativePath":null,"height":0,"length":166,"width":0,"mimeType":"text/html","apiName":"Ti.Blob","text":"Array\n(\n
>   [uploadToken] => hi! I am a token!\n    [myNickname] => raholl\n
>   [nativePath] =>
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app-name/tia-217296905.jpg\n)\n","type":2,"bubbleParent":true},"autoRedirect":true,"apiName":"Ti.Network.HTTPClient","autoEncodeUrl":true,"connected":false,"bubbleParent":true,"_events":{"disposehandle":{}}},"success":true}
>   [INFO] :   ALERT: (KrollRuntimeThread) [8,13696] done

What row is this "Error parsing XML [ERROR]" coming from? How to fix it?

Everything appears to work just fine, but the error looks quite serious...

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

LOL it was

```
console.log(e);
```

in the

```
xhr.onload = function(e){
 divider("ONLOAD DONE");
 //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
 //console.log(e);
 alert("done");
};
```

Without console.log, no error appears and everything works fine. Probably **e** was empty or not valid object for logging...

Comment: LOL, i was logging the whole response object .. and getting the same problem?! Thanks, you helped me out!